# Wi-Fi options not available after using Virtual Box

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I have recently started to use virtual box which I installed on windows 10 - 64 bit as base OS and now I am getting issues with accessing Wi-Fi on my main OS. Options to turn on Wi-Fi disappear and comeback again randomly on my PC especially when I use virtual box in regular intervals. I have tried every available solution available on the internet including updating/ reinstalling the drivers and Wi-Fi option still comes and goes back without doing anything.
Please let me know is this problem actually related to my use of virtual box and How can I solve this.

Comment: Does it happen while you're running VMs only or always?

Comment: It does not happen while the VM is running, but it does happen at times after I close the VM.

Comment: Could be some USB or PCi passtrough incorrectly configured in Virtualbox.